# Como usar uma variável contida em outra página PHP?

Tags: php, back-end

Galera, boa tarde.
Como faço para utilizar uma variável de um arquivo X.php na página Y.php ?
Quero por exemplo fazer o seguinte:

```
<?php
    $Frase = "minha frase";
?>
```

Na minha página Y quero pegar o valor de uma destas variáveis, exemplo:

```
<h3>
<?php $Frase; ?>
```

Como poderia receber o resultado dessas variáveis de outras páginas? alguém teria um exemplo?

Comment: Sim é possível com `include`/`require` ou passando como parâmetro via get/post.

Comment: Como você está recebendo o valor desta variável?

Comment: include('includes/controllers.php');

Comment: É melhor adicionar mais detalhes sobre o seu problema, como funciona esse include, pq precisa passar esse valor para outra página.

Answer (score 8):

Sabendo que o ficheiro "outro_ficheiro.php" tem:

```
<?php
    $frase = "abcdef";
?>
```

Noutro ficheiro (do mesmo diretório) pode ser incluída a variável da seguinte forma:

```
<?php
    include('outro_ficheiro.php');
    echo $frase;
?>
```

Comment: não me retornou nada, amigo

Comment: @JúlioRodrigues ambos os ficheiros estão no mesmo diretório? O código está entre as tags <?php e ?> ?

Comment: Não.. Arquivo X -> Assets(include)   Arquivo Y esta na raiz

Comment: Tens de definir o diretório correto, do ficheiro onde está a variável, no incude.

Comment: Depois do `<?php` adicione esta linha: `error_reporting(E_ALL);
  ini_set("display_errors", 1);` e veja qual o erro que aparece... provavelmente vc está passando o caminho errado, tente assim `include "assets/outro_ficheiro.php;"`...

Comment: Obrigado, Gustavo! Deu certo! Fiz via include! o problema era a forma como especifiquei o caminho! Grato!

Comment: Funciona perfeito, muito obrigado. Meus arquivos estavam uma bagunça hahaha

Answer (score 2):

Por meio de sessão.

### PageX.php

```
<?php
    session_start(); # Deve ser a primeira linha do arquivo

    $frase = "Minha Frase";

    $_SESSION['frase'] = $frase;
?>
```

### PageY.php

```
<?php
    session_start(); # Deve ser a primeira linha do arquivo

    echo $_SESSION['frase'];
?>
```

Comment: Só que me retorna Warning: session_start(): Cannot send session cookie - headers already sent by (output started at /home/mktbt/mktbt.com/index.php:18) in /home/mktbt/mktbt.com/index.php on line 348

Warning: session_start(): Cannot send session cache limiter - headers already sent (output started at /home/mktbt/mktbt.com/index.php:18) in /home/mktbt/mktbt.com/index.php on line 348

Comment: Você está colocando o comando na primeira linha do seu arquivo ?

Comment: Sim, esta na primeira linha do meu arquivo. Porém agora não me retorna a mensagem

Comment: Utilizar uma variável de sessão para capturar valores de variáveis, acima de tudo se forem valores de configuração é meio exagerado, e pouco seguro não achas ? Um simples `include` seria suficiente. Ou então, podes explicar em quais situações as sessões são mais proveitosas.

Comment: Ele perguntou se tinha um exemplo. Eu dei um exemplo de vários, como o uso do `include`. Agora, ele não especificou nada na pergunta, então eu falei da sessão. Ele não perguntou nada a mais além disso. Se está preocupado dê uma resposta mais completa.

Comment: Muitos de nós foram afetados no passado, e ainda hoje alguns são afetados, devido a más práticas transmitidas, ou exemplos pouco explícitos de como usar corretamente uma função ou construir árvores de decisões, ou onde melhor se enquadrava cada uma delas, e ainda hoje permanecem essas lacunas em muitos de nós. É mais ou menos isso que eu queria dizer. Se vais exemplificar algo, pensa 2x em como será utilizado daqui a algum tempo. Não precisa de ser perfeito, apenas minimamente lógico.

Comment: Pra mim você apenas filosofou e não falou nada.